# What is the proper way to tell SharePoint not to crawl a deleted site collection?

Tags: search, crawling

We are running SP2013 standard edition. We have scheduled full crawl at weekend and incremental crawl every 15 minutes. Recently we deleted a site collection. After a week when I check the crawl log a number of error is saying `The object was not found. ( Error from SharePoint site: HttpStatusCode NotFound The request failed with HTTP status 404: Not Found` All of these error is about the deleted site collection.

Although I can click the error log and select `remove the item from index` but I think it is not the proper way. May I know how can I make SharePoint forget the deleted site collection?

Comment: Is the site collection really deleted? Removing them using the UI, they still exists for another 30 days. The only way to completely remove them is to use the cmdlt delete-spsite.

Comment: Are you using a dedicated crawl account or something like the Farm account for crawling?

Answer (score 5):

I think, you should run the full crawl to remove the deleted site from index.Crawler try 30 times before make a decison that this file/url no more with sharepoint.

> When the crawler encounters an access denied or a file not found
>   error, the item is deleted from the index if the error was encountered
>   in more than ErrorDeleteCountAllowed consecutive crawls AND the
>   duration since the first error is greater than
>   ErrorDeleteIntervalAllowed hours. If both conditions are not met, the
>   item is retried.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127009(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: An index reset might also be necessary - "Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 prevents accidental deletion of content from the index when the crawler encounters errors during a *full crawl or an incremental crawl*.". Of course you can play with the `ErrorDeleteAccountAllowed` if a reset isn't allowed for whatever reason, but a reset might just be easier.

Answer (score 3):

If deleted site collections still showed in the search result,then make sure below things

A full Crawl against the content source(which belongs to deleted site collections)
If after couple of crawls items still Showed in the result then **reset the search index.**
Another thought, **please make sure the deleted sites also removed from Central admin** Run the **get-spdeletedsites** and check if the deleted site listed their.

Thanks

Comment: What should I do if get-spdeletedsites return the deleted site?

Comment: Remove-SPDeletedSite -Identity GUID of your Deletd Site

then after reset iis and Sharepoint Timer Service and after that Reset Index and Do Full Crawl  and check Crawl Logs

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286316.aspx